# Bare-metal C++ global objects initialization

Tags: c++

I am developing a bare-metal Embedded C++ application and I created this class:

```
class Person{
 
string name ;

int age;

Person() = delete;

Person(string Name , int Age) : name{Name},age{Age} {}

};
```

Now I want to create a global instance of this class as follows:

`Person person1{"Thomas" , 23};`

When will the constructor be invoked ?

Note that there's no operating system. It's a bare-metal embedded application.

Comment: at the start of the application, before main

Comment: Did you try it, does it get invoked at all? Supposedly whatever normally calls `main()` also calls the global constructors before that.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Technically it is implementation-defined and could be delayed until first odr-use (indirectly) from `main`. It is also possible that the compiler will perform static initialization, so that it is never called at runtime. However "bare-metal embedded" indicates to me that there will be platform specifics that may be necessary to consider (e.g. if `main` doesn't exist in a freestanding environment).

Comment: I've reopened the question. None of the duplicates mentioned bare metal applications.

Comment: Do you have global objects in more than one source file?

Comment: `bare-metal` What "bare-metal"? What compiler? what platform?

Comment: Prefer not to use dynamic memory on "bare-metal" embedded systems.  Most embedded systems have small, constrained memory.  Dynamic memory may also lead to fragmentation, which could be bad for an embedded system.  The `std::string` uses dynamic memory.  You may be able to use `operator new` to change the memory allocation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, although `person1` isn't constant-initialized, the compiler is allowed to perform this initialization as static initialization instead of dynamic initialization, in which case there won't be any constructor call at runtime. I am not sure whether compilers will do this for such a situation, but I am pretty sure they effectively can do so at most if the provided string is small enough to fit in the string's SSO buffer.

Otherwise, if dynamic initialization is performed, in a hosted environment, it is implementation-defined whether the constructor is called before `main` is entered or whether it will be delayed. If delayed, it will be called before the first non-initialization odr-use of any non-`inline` variable or non
`inline` function defined in the same translation unit as `person1`. Non-initialization odr-use means any odr-use that doesn't happen as a result of an initialization of a global variable, i.e. typically an odr-use (indirectly) from `main`. This delay is e.g. typical for dynamic libraries.

If dynamic initialization is performed in a freestanding environment, then startup is completely implementation-defined. It is up to the implementation whether, when and how dynamic initialization of global variables is performed.

If you are on bare-metal, you are probably in a freestanding environment, e.g. one without `main` as entry point, and so the behavior is completely implementation-defined. Without knowing what compiler and platform you are working with, it is impossible to tell. It is possible that the global initialization is not done automatically as in hosted environments and that you must do something specific to have the constructors be called.

Comment: TL;DR: "It depends".  Without knowing what compiler and platform you are working with, it is impossible to tell.  *IN GENERAL* (for most compilers on most platforms, e.g. MSVC on Windows, or gcc on Linux), Alan Birtles is correct: "at the start of the application, before main"

Comment: Toolchains for embedded targets normally have extra linker and compiler options. It is best to check the IDE for project settings in that regards. It must be possible to toggle some build switch, iff the default behaviour specified in std is not desirable in an embedded environment. I guess whatever the entry point function is treated like `main` in std environments, and everything applies to that entry point as the replacement for `main`.